# Is closure enough for an operation to be chained?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Say we have a set S and a binary operation $\star$ **under which S is closed**. Is this *enough* for us to derive an arbitrary (possibly infinitary) operation $\star$ in which **the order of operations carried out does not affect the final result**, and is defined as:

$$
\star(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots) = a_0 \star a_1 \star a_2 \star \ldots \iff a_i \in S \land i \leq n
$$

If not, what other requirements must S and $\star$ satisfy for the above identity to hold?

The examples for such operations include:

| Operation | Set | Closed? | Commutative? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Addition | Real numbers | Yes | Yes |
| Multiplication | Real numbers | Yes | Yes |
| Multiplication | Matrices | Yes | No |
| Concatenation | Sequences | Yes | No |

Answer (score 1):

Okay as I was writing this I realized **associativity** is also required. All those four examples are associative.